# How to identify a Bluetooth peripheral related to an input device?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, input-devices

I want to use multiple Bluetooth input devices on a Linux as `/dev/input` and write a program to handle their input event, but I need to vary its behavior depending on the source peripheral. How do we identify which peripheral originates the received input event?

Background:

I'm working on a personal project to develop a *call button* for a [home robot](https://kachaka.life/) without using its official smartphone app. The robot will come for you if you push the button arranged in every room.

I make use of *Smartphone Shutter Remote Controller* (BT Shutter), a $1 Bluetooth peripheral to tap a shutter button on your smartphone from a distance. It is actually a one-button Bluetooth keyboard that can only send a `VolumeUp` keyboard event to the paired central device. I think it is ideal to implement my use case regarding cost and battery life.

I plan to develop a gateway server in Python on a Linux device like Rasberry Pi that acts as a Bluetooth central and sends a control command to the robot via its API in response to receiving keyboard events from the BT Shutters, like the following:

```py
import evdev

device = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event1')

for event in device.read_loop():
    if (
        event.type == evdev.ecodes.EV_KEY
        and event.code == evdev.ecodes.KEY_VOLUMEUP
        and event.value == 1:  # KEYDOWN
    ):
        # Move the robot to the defined location in the house.
        ...
```

However, the server cannot distinguish the events from different rooms because BT Shutter is just a single-function keyboard and cannot upgrade its firmware to make it send a unique identifier. It would be helpful if it could retrieve the MAC address or something of the input device to identify the source of the events. Note that the device name `/event?` is not reliable because evdev does not ensure its consistency between re-connection.

[image: Smartphone Shutter Remote Controller]

Comment: What language are going to write the program in? Python has a library that should be able to help https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Comment: Hi. I already investigated evdev, but unfortunately it doesn’t help because it is not able to get metadata of the source of input devices.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the reference to the guide lines. But it doesn’t make sense. I already “tried” to investigate and the question I described is the specific roadblock of my issue. I have some BLE input devices and need to distinct their events each other in my program on Linux. I need to get the metadata of the source of the input events, but I don’t know how to achieve it. Do you know the solution to this issue?

Comment: If you could show use a (minimal) program that works for a single device, that would be a start - then at least we'd know which programming language to tag the question with.  And if you have an equivalent program for a different device, then we might be able to understand the requirements better.

Comment: @ukBaz I finnally found that `InputDevice` in python-evdev has `phys` property that indicates the MAC address of the underlying Bluetooth peripheral. Thanks!

Comment: @TobySpeight It is a language-agnostic question because I just asked about the features or specifications of Linux. Please see the following answer of mine.

Comment: @TobySpeight Hi, could you explain why downvote my question and answer?

Comment: The edits to the question addressed my concerns; it's much better now.  And I didn't downvote your answer - you're making assumptions that aren't warranted (I'm only just now seeing your answer).

Comment: Ah, sorry. Anyway thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `/dev/input/event*` provides a `UNIQ` identifier in response to the `EVIOCGUNIQ` [ioctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) request. In the case of Bluetooth, UNIQ [represents a MAC address](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/c159d790e8786581cfa5e5a9e7bd71458a343e44/profiles/input/device.c#L947) to identify the underlying peripheral uniquely. evdev also exposes `PRODUCT` via `EVIOCGID` request.

We can easily get the value in Python by using [python-evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/), that provides a [convenient wrapper function](https://github.com/gvalkov/python-evdev/blob/39ba89ce5b40e05ab1304882c4cd14df6222b5da/evdev/input.c#L232-L240) of ioctl:

```py
>>> import evdev
>>> dev = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event1')
>>> dev.name
'BT Shutter Keyboard'
>>> dev.info
DeviceInfo(bustype=5, vendor=9354, product=33382, version=1)
>>> dev.phys  # Controller MAC address
'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'
>>> dev.uniq  # Device MAC address
'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'
```

`udevadm` also provides the event device path that includes the path to the underlying input device on sysfs:

```bash
$ udevadm info /dev/input/event1
P: /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX/input/input1/event1
N: input/event1
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX/input/input1/event1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event1
...

$ udevadm info /sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX/input/input1
PRODUCT=5/248a/8266/1
NAME="BT Shutter Keyboard"
PHYS="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
UNIQ="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
...
```